# ¿Cómo poner guión entre números en php?

Tags: php

Me explico; desde la bd estoy trayendo unos datos, estos son números, lo que quiero es separarlos con un (-).

Este es el que código del dato que quiero separar con el (-):

```
<td>
    <select style="border-radius: 5px; width: 105px; height: 30px;" id="obra1" name="obra1" >
         <option value="0">Código Obra</option>
         <?php foreach($obra as $obras)                 
               {
                 echo "<option value=" . $obras['id_bautizo_obra']. ">" . $obras['id_bautizo_obra']. "</option>";                                                   
               }
         ?>
     </select>

</td>
```

Comment: Que es exactamente lo que quieres separar?

Comment: es un select, medio complicado separar cada option con "-" , una imagen de como debe quedar?

Comment: Cada opcion viene como una linea separada, quieres poner un guion antes o despues de cada opcion?

Comment: Me explico, dígamos que el dato que viene desde la bd es "14081", lo que yo quiero es que el guión me los separe así "14-081".

Comment: Siempre va a ser el mismo formato, digo siempre van a ser 5 numeros y el guion siempre va a ir despues del segundo numero?

Comment: Sí, siempre va a ser el mismo formato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
<td>
<select style="border-radius: 5px; width: 105px; height: 30px;" id="obra1" name="obra1" >
     <option value="0">Código Obra</option>
     <?php foreach($obra as $obras)                 
           {
             echo "<option value=" . substr($obras['id_bautizo_obra'],0,2). "-". substr($obras['id_bautizo_obra'],2,3). ">" . substr($obras['id_bautizo_obra'],0,2). "-". substr($obras['id_bautizo_obra'],2,3). "</option>";                     
           }
     ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Siempre me salvas la vida, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada Maria.  Solo unas sugerencias.  Deberias de poner los detalles en tu pregunta, de esa forma no tenemos que sacarte la informacion en los comentarios.  Tambien puedes votar a favor de las respuestas que te ayudaron.

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente te recomiendo que le quites los espacios al codigo para que quede mas legible, porque ahora hay que escrollear al costado para verlo bien.

Cualquier string que quieras unir con "-" deberias hacerlo mediante concatenación, por ejemplo:

```
$variable . "-" . $otraVariable
```

Es lo que venis haciendo con html pero con el campo numero que estas intentando utilizar.